# Counting Function calls in ISO C89

Tags: c, function, counting, function-calls, ansi-c

I have to write a function in C for my homework.
Given the functions is_prime(n) and nth_prime(n),the first returning 1 if n  is prime(or 0 if it's not) and nth_prime returning the nth prime number, i have to write the function next_prime(count) which counts the time it's called and then returns the "count-th" number prime.
count must be a static unsigned int variable.
If n=0 (n is given with a scanf ),count value must be reset to  0,and the function returns the first prime number,2.
I can't use structures,arrays or recursion.
I'm new to coding,and I don't know what to do.
I use Visual Studio 2010 and I have to compile it as ISO C89(ANSI C).
The functions must be written in a library file,the only thing that's going to be evaluated,so I can't use a count++ in the main () function.
Here's what I've done so far.

```
unsigned int next_prime( unsigned int count ) {
    if( count == 0 ) {
        if ( n=!0 ) {                       
            return nth_prime( count );
            count++;
        } else {
            count = 0;
            return 2;
        }      
    } else {    
        if ( n=!0 ) {                       
            return nth_prime( count );
        } else {
            count = 0;
            return 2; 
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `n=!0` be `n!=0`?

Comment: Begin with creating static unsigned int variable `count`.

Comment: I've created it but I put it outside the function body.
Is it wrong?
Yes,it's n!=0,I made I mistake.
I apologize.

Comment: If you have to write the function `next_prime(count)`, it is wrong because the global `count` will be shadowed by the argument `count` and cannot be accessed inside the function `next_prime`.

Comment: I've done it but Visual Studio gives me a "redefinition of formal parameter count" error C2082

     unsigned int next_prime(unsigned int count) {
     static unsigned int count n=0;
     if(count == 0)
     {
     if (n=!0) {                     
     return nth_prime(count);
     count++;}
     else {count = 0; return 2;}    
     }
    else
     {  if (n=!0) {                     

      return nth_prime(count);
     }
     else {count = 0;return 2; }       
     }

     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that will meet your question:

```
/* the function next_prime(count) */
unsigned int next_prime(unsigned int count) {
    /* avoid "unused parameter" warning */
    (void)count;
    /* introduce this block because defining the variable count here will read to an redeclaring error */
    {
        static unsigned int count = 0;
        int n = -1;
        /* n is given with a scanf */
        scanf("%d", &n);
        /* if n=0 */
        if (n == 0) {
            /* count value must be reset to 0 */
            count = 0;
            /* return the first prime number, 2 */
            return 2;
        } else {
            /* count the time it is called */
            count++;
            /* return the "count-th" prime number */
            return nth_prime(count);
        }
    }
}
```